# Mysql select ordering different as subquery vs. query in 5.7.x

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

Let me preface this with by saying that what I'm describing here was working just fine in Mysql 5.6.x and lower.  Now we're trying to update to mysql 5.7 and finding an issue with this UPDATE statement.

We have a table that looks like this:

```
imagefile
----------
id      int
itemId  int
...
sequenceNumber int
updatedDate    date
```

In our application it is necessary for users to reorder imageFiles within the Item.  Our SQL to do that looks like this:

```
UPDATE imageFile f1 
  JOIN ( 
        SELECT f2.id, (@row:=@row+1) rowNum 
          FROM imageFile f2, (SELECT @row:=0) dm 
         WHERE f2.itemId = 8035323
         ORDER BY f2.sequenceNumber, f2.updatedDate 
        ) rs ON f1.id = rs.id 
SET f1.sequenceNumber = rs.rowNum;
```

If I run just the select part as a stand-alone query it produces this:

```
SELECT f2.id, f2.sequenceNumber, sqNum (@row:=@row+1) rowNum, updatedDate 
  FROM imageFile f2, (SELECT @row:=0) dm 
 WHERE f2.itemId = 8035323
 ORDER BY f2.sequenceNumber, f2.updatedDate;

 id   sqNum   rowNum   updatedDate
| 9 |   1   |   1   |2018-04-16 18:39:12
| 8 |   2   |   2   |2018-04-16 18:38:42
| 7 |   3   |   3   |2018-04-16 18:37:03
| 6 |   4   |   4   |2018-04-16 18:37:28
| 5 |   5   |   5   |2018-04-16 18:36:37
| 4 |   6   |   6   |2018-04-16 18:38:16
| 3 |   7   |   7   |2017-09-12 16:59:20
```

Which is correct and exactly what I expect...
After I run the UPDATE with the SELECT as the subquery/join I get this:

```
 id   sqNum  rowNum   updatedDate
| 3 |   1   |   1   |2017-09-12 16:59:20
| 4 |   2   |   2   |2018-04-16 18:38:16
| 5 |   3   |   3   |2018-04-16 18:36:37
| 6 |   4   |   4   |2018-04-16 18:37:28
| 7 |   5   |   5   |2018-04-16 18:37:03
| 8 |   6   |   6   |2018-04-16 18:38:42
| 9 |   7   |   7   |2018-04-16 18:39:12
```

Which is completely wrong and doesn't seem to follow any order by that I told it to.  Obviously something changed in the new version of mysql.  When I do the EXPLAIN for that query in each version it's different as well...

5.6.34

```
id  select_type table   type    possible keys   key key length  ref rows    extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    35  NULL
1   PRIMARY i1  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   rs.id   1   NULL
2   DERIVED <derived3>  system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   Using filesort
2   DERIVED i2  ref uc_ItemNumber, in_workspaceId   uc_ItemNumber   4   const   35  Using where
3   DERIVED NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
```

5.7.18

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL                 35  
1   UPDATE  i1  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   rs.id   1   
2   DERIVED i2  ref uc_ItemNumber, in_workspaceId   uc_ItemNumber   4   const   35  Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED <derived3>  ALL                 1   Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
3   DERIVED                             No tables used
```

My question is how do I get this to go back to the previous/desired behavior?

Comment: I seem to recall that session variables should not be used in DML statements, or at least that the behavior is not guaranteed (as you are now saying).  Let me try to find a doc reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to recall that session variables should not be used/relied upon for MySQL DML statements.  But the good news is that we can rewrite your query without session variables:

```
UPDATE imageFile f1 
INNER JOIN
( 
    SELECT
        f2.id, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM imageFile t
     WHERE t.itemId = 8035323 AND
           (t.sequenceNumber < f2.sequenceNumber OR
            t.sequenceNumber = f2.sequenceNumber AND
            (t.updatedDate < f2.updatedDate OR
            (t.updatedDate = f2.updatedDate AND t.id < f2.id)))) rowNum
    FROM imageFile f2
    WHERE f2.itemId = 8035323
) rs
    ON f1.id = rs.id 
SET f1.sequenceNumber = rs.rowNum;
```

Comment: thank you for the response.  maybe I'm dense but this query gives me an sql error.   it doesn't like something in the "f2.updatedDate FROM imageFile t)" area

Comment: Sorry I had a typo please try it again.

Comment: I edited another typo I think (please confirm) and tried this.  Just the subquery select takes 97 seconds to run by itself and gives some pretty crazy results...rowNum values are:  8327423, 12524473, 15670143...

Comment: Oops...I forgot the condition `itemId = 8035323` in the correlated subquery.  Try again.

Comment: I believe we have a winner!  Thank you!  I've tested this in my development environment and it seems to work.

Comment: I did try googling for something like this but I'm not even sure what to search for...What terms do you suggest using to give me some documentation on this issue?

Comment: Try Googling for "SQL rolling sum correlated," or something like that.  Note that my code may still have a problem if two or more records happen to have the same `sequenceNumber` and `updatedDate` values.  In this case, we'd need to break the tie somehow to keep the row number behaving as we want.

Comment: I added an 'or' to the inner select and added to your answer above.

Comment: You need slightly different logic than what you wrote to break the tie.